# Laravel 5: Krlove method does not exist

Tags: php, laravel, model

I installed Krlove Model generator on a project, I did every step to install it. However when I run this command:

```
php artisan krlove:generate:model Role --table-name=roles
```

It throws this error:

> [ReflectionException]
>     Method Krlove\EloquentModelGenerator\Command\GenerateModelCommand::handle()
>      does not exist

I ran `composer require krlove/eloquent-model-generator --dev` and then I registered the service at **config/app.php**: `Krlove\EloquentModelGenerator\Provider\GeneratorServiceProvider::class,`

But it still doesn't work, if I'm missing a step please let me know, thanks in advance.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload`?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, still not working, it's strange.

Comment: I don't have an idea maybe you can checkup in the repo of the package you are using perhaps there is a fix or similar behavior reported. Or you should ensure that you properly setup your config file

Comment: will the command be shown if you run `php artisan`?

Comment: Hi, sorry for the late answer, yes it does,

Answer (score 1):

It is because you're running your app in a different ENV than dev.

This package will be installed only on a dev env when you run:

`composer require krlove/eloquent-model-generator --dev`

Answer (score 0):

```
php artisan krlove:generate:model --connection=mysql_xxxx Role --table-name=roles
```

Try to specify the database connection to try, I have multiple databases, he did not go to the default database, I specify the database connection will be OK, this is my solution, for reference